# Uploading and parsing text document in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

In my application, the user must upload a text document, the contents of which are then parsed by the receiving controller action. I've gotten the document to upload successfully, but I'm having trouble reading its contents.

There are several threads on this issue. I've tried more or less everything recommended on these threads, and I'm still unable to resolve the problem.

Here is my code:

```
file_data = params[:file]

contents = ""

if file_data.respond_to?(:read)
  contents = file_data.read
else
  if file_data.respond_to?(:path)
    File.open(file_data, 'r').each_line do |line|
      elts = line.split
      #
      #
    end
  end
end
```

So here are my problems:
file_data doesn't 'respond_to?' either :read or :path. According to some other threads on the topic, if the uploaded file is less than a certain size, it's interpreted as a string and will respond to :read. Otherwise, it should respond to :path. But in my code, it responds to neither.

If I try to take out the if statements and straight away attempt File.open(file_data, 'r'), I get an error saying that the file wasn't found.

Can someone please help me find out what's wrong?

PS, I'm really sorry that this is a redundant question, but I found the other threads unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually storing the file? Because if you are not, of course it can't be found.

Comment: Hmm, I thought uploading the file would store it into a location accessible to the server? I guess not. How would I actually save the file?

Comment: ok it gets saved on a temporary directory. I actually never done this :p here are the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: I'm duplicating the logic on the rubyonrails guide, and I'm running into issues. 

     uploaded_io = params[:file]
     File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'data', params[:file]), 'w') do |file|
        file.write(uploaded_io.read)
     end

I'm getting an error saying that there is no read method for String. It's calling 'read' on uploaded_io, which is the name of the uploaded file.

Comment: make sure you have the upload folder inside the public folder

Comment: In the call to Rails.roots.join, I passed in the parameters 'public' and 'data'. Wouldn't it be enough to have a data folder inside the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

First, find out what you're actually getting for `file_data` by adding debug output of `file_data.inspect`. It maybe something you don't expect, especially if form isn't set up correctly (i.e. `:multipart => true`).

Rails should enclose uploaded file in special object providing uniform interface, so that something as simple as this should work:

```
file_data.read.each_line do |line|
  elts = line.split
  #
  #
end
```

Comment: file_data is a String, the name of the uploaded text file. I've also included :multipart => true in the form submission. Here's the relevant code from my view:

<%= form_tag(:controller => "static_pages", :action => "complete_registration", :multipart => true, :method => "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:file, "Upload Text File:") %>
  <%= file_field_tag(:file) %>
  
  <%= submit_tag("Register") %>

Comment: `multipart` option should go into the second argument of `form_tag`. You're mixing it with url options, so it ends up in url and not in form's `enctype` attribute. Try changing your view code to this: `<%= form_tag(:controller => "static_pages", :action => "complete_registration", {:multipart => true, :method => "post"}) do %>`